# How do i make $a[$aa] work in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a program that has the code like so:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$value = ""
$machineChanged = $false


$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.WindowState = "Maximized"
$form.Text = "Python Interpreter"

$TextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox.Location = "0, 100"
$TextBox.Size = "1920, 800"
$TextBox.Multiline = $true
$TextBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 30, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$TextBox.ReadOnly = $false

$output = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$output.Location = "0,900"
$output.BackColor = "LightGray"
$output.Size = "1920,235"
$output.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 30, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$output.IsAccessible = $true
$output.Add_TextChanged{
    if($machineChanged -eq $true){
        $value = $output.Text
    }else{
        $aa, $aaa = $output.Text.Split($value)
    }
}

$run = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$run.Text = "Run"
$run.Size = "150, 100"
$run.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 30, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$run.Add_Click(
{
    $Script:output.Text = ""
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$lol = $TextBox.Text.Split("
")
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$varstore = @()
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$varstoreValue = @()
    $counter = 0
    $countreally = 0
    $e = ""
    $g = ""
    $linecount = 0
    while($counter -lt $lol.Count){
        $re = $lol[$counter]
        if($re -like '*=*'){
            $useful, $useles, $usefu = $lol[$counter].Split(" ")
            $varstore.Add($useful)
            $varstoreValue.Add($usefu)
        }
        if($re -like '*print*'){
            if(-Not ($re -like '*"*')){
                while($true){
                    $e, $g = $re.Split(")")
                    $reee, $help = $e.Split("print(")
                    $help = $help.Replace(' ','')
                    $help = $help.Replace(' ','')
                    if($varstore[$Script:countreally] -like "*$help*"){
                        $Script:machineChanged = $true
                        $Script:output.Text = $Script:output.Text + $Script:varstoreValue[$Script:countreally]
                        $Script:machineChanged = $false
                        $Script:linecount = $Script:linecount + 1
                        break
                    }
                    $countreally = $countereally + 1
                }
            }else{
                $haha, $xd = $lol[$counter].Split('"')
                $e,$g = $xd.Split(")")
                $machineChanged = $true
                $Script:output.Text = $Script:output.text + $e
                $machinechanged = $false
                $linecount = $linecount + 1
            }
        }
        if($re -like "*input*"){
                $haha, $xd = $lol[$counter].Split('"')
                $e,$g = $xd.Split(")")
                $machineChanged = $true
                $Script:output.Text = $Script:output.text + $e
                $machineChanged = $false
        }
        $counter = $counter + 1
        $lol.RemoveRange(0, 1)
    }

}
)

$form.Controls.Add($TextBox)
$form.Controls.Add($run)
$form.Controls.Add($output)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

When I try to launch it and try to type in this code:
"age = 20
print(age)"
without the quotes and click the button run, which I have added, it shows me a box with this info:
The pipeline has been stopped.
Here's the info I got from the details thing with the arrow (thanks for posting, Mathias R. Jessen):

```
    System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
       w System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
       w System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
       w System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
       w System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
       w System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
       w System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
       w System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
       w System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<InvokeWithPipe>b__0()
       w System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
       w System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Boolean propagateAllExceptionsToTop, List`1 variablesToDefine, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, Object[] args)
       w System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsDelegateHelper(Object dollarUnder, Object dollarThis, Object[] args)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       w System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    
    
    ************** Zestawy załadowane **************
    mscorlib
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    powershell_ise
        Wersja zestawu: 3.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/PowerShell_ISE.exe
    ----------------------------------------
    Microsoft.PowerShell.ISECommon
        Wersja zestawu: 3.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.19041.1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.ISECommon/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.ISECommon.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Windows.Forms
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4341.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Drawing
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Management.Automation
        Wersja zestawu: 3.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.19041.1023
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management.Automation/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Management.Automation.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Core
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Configuration
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Xml
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Microsoft.PowerShell.GPowerShell
        Wersja zestawu: 3.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.19041.1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.GPowerShell/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.GPowerShell.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.ComponentModel.Composition
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ComponentModel.Composition/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Microsoft.PowerShell.Editor
        Wersja zestawu: 3.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.19041.1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.Editor/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.Editor.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    WindowsBase
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    PresentationFramework
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    PresentationCore
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/PresentationCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Xaml
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xaml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    UIAutomationProvider
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationProvider/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationProvider.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Runtime.Serialization
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Serialization/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Accessibility
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    MetadataViewProxies_e8833a3b-4954-40a7-9267-07fb9e9037ce
        Wersja zestawu: 0.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ComponentModel.Composition/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Management
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.DirectoryServices
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.DirectoryServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.DirectoryServices.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure
        Wersja zestawu: 1.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.19041.1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    PresentationCore.resources
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationCore.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.resources.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    PresentationFramework.Aero2
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero2/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    PresentationFramework-SystemXml
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemXml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    mscorlib.resources
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Data
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
        Wersja zestawu: 0.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security
        Wersja zestawu: 3.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.19041.1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Numerics
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Transactions
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Microsoft.PowerShell.GraphicalHost
        Wersja zestawu: 3.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.19041.1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.GraphicalHost/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.GraphicalHost.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    UIAutomationTypes
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationTypes/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationTypes.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Microsoft.GeneratedCode
        Wersja zestawu: 1.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    PresentationFramework.resources
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.resources.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    PresentationFramework-SystemData
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4360.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemData/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    PresentationFramework-SystemCore
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.resources
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_b77a5c561934e089/System.resources.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    SMDiagnostics
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/SMDiagnostics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/SMDiagnostics.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.ServiceModel.Internals
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel.Internals/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.RunTime.Serialization.resources
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Serialization.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.resources.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility
        Wersja zestawu: 3.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.19041.804
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Configuration.Install
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration.Install/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.Install.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Windows.UI
        Wersja zestawu: 255.255.255.255
        Wersja Win32: 10.0.10011.16384
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.UI.winmd
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Microsoft.CSharp
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.CSharp/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.CSharp.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Dynamic
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Dynamic/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Dynamic.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Windows.Forms.resources
        Wersja zestawu: 4.0.0.0
        Wersja Win32: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    
    ************** Debugowanie w trybie JIT **************
    Aby włączyć debugowanie w trybie just in time (JIT), plik .config tej
    aplikacji lub komputera (machine.config) musi mieć
    wartość jitDebugging ustawioną w sekcji system.windows.forms.
    Aplikacja musi być również skompilowana z włączonym
    debugowaniem.
    
    Na przykład:
    
    <configuration>
        <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
    </configuration>
    
    Gdy debugowanie JIT jest włączone, wszystkie nieobsługiwane wyjątki
    są wysyłane do debugera JIT zarejestrowanego na komputerze
    i nie są obsługiwane w tym oknie dialogowym.
```

Thanks.

Comment: "I can give all the info, but it's super long and wouldn't be understandable anyways." - give it a try, maybe someone will surprise you

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try.